# Phaser as a replacement for CountdownLatch

Tags: java, concurrency

Are there any benefits in terms of performance, memory, improvements, robustness, etc to use a `Phaser` as a replacement for a `CountdownLatch`?

For example, `myCountDownLatch()` behaves the same as `myPhaser()`:

**Version 1 with CountdownLatch:**

```
public static void myCountDownLatch() {

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Thread t = new Thread(() ->
        {
            try {
                log.info("CountDownLatch: in thread..");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        });
        t.start();
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("CountDownLatch: out thread..");
    }
```

**Version 2 with Phaser:**

```
public static void myPhaser() {

        Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
        Thread t = new Thread(() ->
        {
            try {
                log.info("phaser: in thread..");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
        });
        t.start();
        // 1. benefit: With phaser we dont need to manage the InterruptedException ourselves.
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        log.info("phaser: out thread..");

    }
```

Or are there any better replacements for a `CountdownLatch` in java?

Comment: Not in the context you've used them.  But `Phaser`s can be reused (so you don't need to keep making new instances), can handle changing numbers of parties over time (hence the `deregister` in your call), and are just generally more flexible.  They're really for different use-cases though, so use whichever one best suits what you're doing.

Comment: With `phaser` we dont need to manage the `InterruptedException` ourselves.

Comment: A `Phaser` implements the `ManagedBlocker` which ensures that a new thread is created if the phaser blocks a thread..this is not the case with `CountdownLatch`, but I think for **my use case** there is never a need for the `ManagedBlocker`, or?

Comment: I replaced all my `CountDownLatch()` codes with a `Phaser()`. I dont know if it is better now. However, I get rid of the `InterruptedException` which I must catch when using a `CountDownLatch`. So with a `Phaser`, it is less code at the end. And it seems that it works **exactly the same.**

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.infoq.com/news/2008/07/phasers/

> Performance results obtained from a portable implementation of phasers on three different SMP platforms demonstrate that they can deliver superior performance to existing barrier implementations, in addition to the productivity benefits that result from their generality and safety properties.

For more details check [JSR 166](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=166)

Comment: Hi thanks for the link. However, does this mean that the `myPhaser` delievers better performance than `myCountDownLatch`? Does this mean that I should use **Version 2 (with Phaser)**? I only want to have a `Phaser` as a 1:1 replacement for the `CountdownLatch` and dont make use of any other Phaser`s capabilities.

Comment: I think for normal use given by you in example there won't be any diff you can measure, for details you have to read the JSR. I don't have detailed knowledge.